No access to services through treafik with cloudflared
I am working with docker-compose to spin up Traefik and Cloudflared. However, I keep having an issue with being unable to send traffic through Traefik. But when I set up the DNS in the Cloudflare tunnel to remove the container directly it works, so I know my problem is traffic. Is there anyone who might be able to give me some pointers on what I may have done wrong? my files are stored in this repo: https://github.com/SinLess-Games/System-Critical-Services
docker-compose.yaml
# Define Docker networks to segment and manage communication between services.
networks:
  backend:                                        # Backend network for inter-service communication (e.g., databases, APIs)
    name: backend                                 # Custom network name for clarity
    driver: overlay                               # Overlay network spans multiple Docker nodes in a swarm
    attachable: true                              # Allows standalone containers to connect to this network
  
  frontend:                                       # Frontend network for user-facing services (e.g., web interfaces)
    name: frontend                                # Custom name for the frontend network
    driver: bridge                              # Overlay network enables scalability and multi-node communication
    attachable: true                              # Allows additional containers to attach dynamically

services:
  cloudflared:
    image: cloudflare/cloudflared:2024.2.1
    container_name: cloudflared
    restart: always
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    command: >
      tunnel --no-autoupdate run --token ${CLOUDFLARE_TUNNEL_TOKEN}
    environment:
      TZ: "${TZ:-UTC}"
      CLOUDFLARE_TUNNEL_TOKEN: ${CLOUDFLARE_TUNNEL_TOKEN}
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
      resources:
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.10'
          memory: 2048M
        limits:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 2048M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
  
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v3.2.2                # Use Traefik version 3.2.2
    container_name: traefik             # Name the container 'traefik'
    restart: always                     # Restart on failure or crash
    privileged: true                    # Allow privileged mode (required for some features)
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges=true          # Prevent privilege escalation
    depends_on:
      cloudflared:                      # Ensure cloudflared starts before Traefik
        condition: service_started
    ports:
      - 443:443                         # HTTPS
      - 80:80                           # HTTP
      - 8080:8080                       # Traefik Dashboard (optional)
    networks:
      frontend:                         # Connect to frontend network
        aliases:
          - traefik-scs-dashboard.${LOCAL_DOMAIN}
          - traefik-scs-dashboard.${DOMAIN}
      backend:                          # Connect to backend network
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro       # Synchronize container time
      - /run/docker.sock:/run/docker.sock:ro   # Access Docker socket for dynamic routing
      - ./config/traefik.yaml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yaml:ro  # Traefik static config
      - ./.data/logs:/var/traefik/logs:rw      # Persistent logs
      - ./.data/certs/:/var/traefik/certs/:rw  # Persistent certs
      - ./config/conf.d:/rules                 # Custom routing rules
    labels:
      # Enable Traefik
      - "traefik.enable=true"

      # Domain routing
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-scs-dashboard_domain-http.rule=Host(`traefik-scs-dashboard.${DOMAIN}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-scs-dashboard_domain-http.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-scs-dashboard_domain-http.middlewares=redirect-to-https"

      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-scs-dashboard_domain-https.rule=Host(`traefik-scs-dashboard.${DOMAIN}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-scs-dashboard_domain-https.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-scs-dashboard_domain-https.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-scs-dashboard_domain-https.tls.certresolver=cloudflare"

      # HTTPS Redirect Middleware
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.permanent=true"

      # Watchtower support
      - "com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.enable=true"
    environment:
      CF_API_EMAIL: "${CF_API_EMAIL}"                # Cloudflare API Email
      CF_DNS_API_TOKEN: "${CF_DNS_API_TOKEN}"        # Cloudflare DNS API Token
      TZ: "${TZ:-UTC}"                               # Timezone
      DOMAIN: ${DOMAIN}                              # Production domain
    deploy:
      replicas: 1                                    # Single replica
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager                     # Run only on manager nodes
      resources:
        reservations:
          cpus: "0.25"                               # Reserve 0.25 CPU
          memory: 256M                               # Reserve 256MB memory
        limits:
          cpus: "0.50"                               # Limit to 0.5 CPU
          memory: 512M                               # Limit to 512MB memory
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure                        # Restart on failure
        delay: 5s                                    # Wait 5 seconds before restarting
        max_attempts: 3                              # Retry up to 3 times

traefik.yaml
# Traefik 3.x (YAML)
# Updated 2024-December-17
# Traefik V3 yaml schema
# yaml-language-server: $schema=https://json.schemastore.org/traefik-v3.json
################################################################
# Global configuration - https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/reference/static-configuration/file/
################################################################
global:
  checkNewVersion: false
  sendAnonymousUsage: true

serversTransport:
  insecureSkipVerify: true

################################################################
# Entrypoints - https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/entrypoints/
################################################################
entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"

  https:
    address: ":443"
    http:
      tls:
        certResolver: cloudflare
        domains:
          - main: "sinlessgamesllc.com"
            sans:
              - "*.sinlessgamesllc.com"
    forwardedHeaders:
      trustedIPs:
        # Cloudflare IPs (https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v4)
        - "173.245.48.0/20"
        - "103.21.244.0/22"
        - "103.22.200.0/22"
        - "103.31.4.0/22"
        - "141.101.64.0/18"
        - "108.162.192.0/18"
        - "190.93.240.0/20"
        - "188.114.96.0/20"
        - "197.234.240.0/22"
        - "198.41.128.0/17"
        - "162.158.0.0/15"
        - "104.16.0.0/13"
        - "104.24.0.0/14"
        - "172.64.0.0/13"
        - "131.0.72.0/22"
        # Local IPs
        - "127.0.0.1/32"
        - "10.0.0.0/8"
        - "192.168.0.0/16"
        - "172.16.0.0/12"
        - "192.168.86.0/24"

################################################################
# Logs - https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/observability/logs/
################################################################
log:
  level: INFO # Options: DEBUG, PANIC, FATAL, ERROR (Default), WARN, and INFO
  filePath: /var/traefik/logs/traefik-container.log
  # format: json # Uses text format (common) by default

################################################################
# Access logs - https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/observability/access-logs/
################################################################
accessLog:
  filePath: /var/traefik/logs/traefik-access.log
  bufferingSize: 100 # Number of log lines
  fields:
    names:
      StartUTC: drop # Write logs in Container Local Time instead of UTC
  filters:
    statusCodes:
      - "204-299"
      - "400-499"
      - "500-599"

################################################################
# API and Dashboard
################################################################
api:
  dashboard: true
  # Rely on api@internal and Traefik with Middleware to control access
  insecure: true

################################################################
# Providers - https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/providers/docker/
################################################################
providers:
  docker:
    exposedByDefault: false
    watch: true
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    network: "frontend"
  file:
    directory: /rules
    watch: true
  redis:
    endpoints:
      - redis:6379

################################################################
# Let's Encrypt (ACME)
################################################################
certificatesResolvers:
  cloudflare:
    acme:
      email: disdainful777@gmail.com # Replace with your Cloudflare email
      storage: /var/traefik/certs/cf-acme.json
      # caServer: "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" # Production Let's Encrypt server
      caServer: "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" # Staging Let's Encrypt server
      dnsChallenge:
        provider: cloudflare
        delayBeforeCheck: 10s
        resolvers:
          - "1.1.1.1:53"
          - "1.0.0.1:53"

################################################################
# TLS Options (https://jellyfin.org/docs/general/networking/traefik2.html#traefik-providertoml)
# toml -> yml
# 2024 updates to cipherSuites from (https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/traefik-v3-docker-compose-guide-2024/)
#
# Set secure options by disabling insecure older TLS/SSL versions
# and insecure ciphers. SNIStrict disabled leaves TLS1.0 open.
# If you have problems with older clients, you may need to relax
# these minimums. This configuration will give you an A+ SSL security
# score supporting TLS1.2 and TLS1.3
#
# Dynamic configuration
# https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/https/tls/
################################################################
tls:
  options:
    default:
      minVersion: VersionTLS12
      sniStrict: true
      curvePreferences:
        - CurveP256
        - CurveP384
        - CurveP521
      cipherSuites:
        - TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        - TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        - TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
        - TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        - TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        - TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256

I can't seem to get treafik to route to containers properly, even after specifying in the tunnel DNS how to get to there. But if I point it directly to the container it will work, but routing through Traefik does not.
My question is what did I do wrong with my configuration that broke it?
Even though traefik spins up and is accessible, when I got to one love my URLs I get
502 Bad Gateway
Unable to reach the origin service. The service may be down or it may not be responding to traffic from cloudflared

But I am able to verify that traefik is up and running without error
